# arrumar conteúdos na views e eliminar os espaços em branco que estão aparecendo

Tags: angularjs, grid

Estou com o problema de listar elementos em minha views, estes elemntos devem aparecer em conjunto sem espaços em branco que os separe. Para resolver essa questão eu tentei usar masonry, sem sucesso, e não tenho ideia de como fazer essa arrumação!

```
<div id="services">
   <div class="box" ng-repeat="service in services">
       <div class="col-5">
          <a class="service-card"  href="{{ service.url }}">
            <h3>{{service.name}}</h3>
                <p ng-bind-html="service.description | limitTo:150 " ><p>{{service.description.length >=   150  ? "..." : " "}}</p><p class="btn">ver mais</p></p>
                <span ng-repeat="category in service.categories">{{ category.name }}.</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este trecho de código que é responsável por controlar a aparição dos elementos na views. 
Grato pela atenção!

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente não tive ajuda aqui, grato pela correção feita na formatação do código que expus. Para que o mesmo caso que perguntei fique com solução vou postar a solução que encontrei.

```html
<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 200 }'>
   <div class="col-6" style="width: 250px;height: 350px; padding: 0;margin: 0;text-align: center;" ng-repeat="service in services">
   <a class="service-card" href="{{ service.url }}">
  <h3 class="title" >{{service.name}}</h3>
  <p ng-bind-html="service.description | limitTo:150 " style="list-style: none;margin: 24px;display: inline-block;font-size: 2em;" ><p>{{service.description.length >=   1  ? "..." : " "}}</p><p class="btn">ver mais</p></p>
     <span ng-repeat="category in service.categories">{{ category.name }}.</span>
 </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pronto, este código consegue listar os elementos e eliminar os buracos em branco que apareciam!